# Absorption coefficients is composed 2 parts, is there any other quantity to measure only the transmitted part?

Tags: acoustics

It seems that [acoustic absorption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_(acoustics)) is composed 2 parts: transformed into heat and transmitted through the absorping materials.

In the context of soundproofing, in particular, acoustically isolated from outside noise, it seems that the transmitted part need to be prevented through into a room.

So, is there any other quantity to measure only the transmitted part?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the general idea of sound insulation is to prevent sound coming in, or going out into or from a room/space. Sound insulation is more concerned about not allowing sound reaching the interior of a room and not so much as to what this energy will become. In this context, you will encounter many designs where creating reflections in layers inside the construction is the purpose of the design. This is most often achieved with impedance mismatches and "tuning" of systems to resonate in different frequencies to avoid excessive deeps in the sound insulation.

Now, this is not always the case though, and for this reason, you will often see absorption material being placed in "sandwich" panels/constructions, or on the sides of double glass windows. So, in general, both attenuation/absorption through heat transformation and reflections are utilised in the sound insulation field /design. But you should keep in mind that "what happens to the energy" and whether this will return to "where it came from" (reflection) or get dissipated as heat (attenuation/absorption) is not always the main concern (it is quite often the last thing an acoustic consultant will care about).